# Using Ternary Operator In Echo Statement

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I'm trying to use a ternary operator but the outcome is not right. I've followed the manual but have no idea what's going on. The outpout in the console is messy.

**php**

```
echo '<div class="item'.(($month_number==='09' && $month_year==='2017')?' active"':"").'>';
```

**console output**

```
<div class="item><div class=" m_page="" outer-div"="">
<div class="inner-div" style=""><div class="momo_p">
```

Comment: Try `echo '<div class="item'.(($month_number==='09' && $month_year==='2017')?' active':'').'">';`

Comment: use  `var_dump($month_number)` and `var_dump($month_year)` to check value and type of variable and share the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reworking of the one liner with the addition of two variables to test the code such that a true result concatenates "active" to  "item".  A false result leads to "item" being concatenated with an empty string, as follows:

```
<?php
$month_number = "08";
$month_year   = "2016";

echo "<div class=\"item";

// making the ternary expression more manageable
$month_result = ($month_number === "09");
$year_result  = ($month_year === "2017");
echo  ($month_result && $year_result)? "active":"";

echo "\"></div>";
```

Live code [here](https://3v4l.org/lkHdq)

Note: if you wish to do one echo statement you could code as follows:

```
$str =  ($month_result && $year_result)? "active":"";
echo "<div class=\"item" . $str  . "\"></div>";
```

See live code [here](https://3v4l.org/0rhAW)

While you could use double quotes for attributes and single quotes for everything else, it is easier to see escaped double quotes for attributes, i.e. \" and double quotes for the outer strings.

Answer (score 2):

Check your quotes.

```
echo '<div class="item'.(($month_number==='10' && $month_year==='2017') ? "active" : "").'">
```

Answer (score 2):

Closing double quotes of class attribute after ternary operator :

```
echo '<div class="item' . (($month_number==='09' && $month_year==='2017') ? ' active' : '') . '">';
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but for some reason now I just get blank page.

Comment: @BalloonFight you can check the page source if it there?

Comment: Yes everything there but the <div class="item">

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<div class="item'.(($month_number==='09' && $month_year==='2017')?' active"':'"').'>';
```

Maybe?

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately same as ravisachaniya. Blank page now.

Comment: If your output is: <div class="item><div class=" m_page="" outer-div"="">
<div class="inner-div" style=""><div class="momo_p">  then there might be something wrong on the div inside <div class="item">, since it has class equals to "m_page=""outer-div"="

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

**PHP**

```
$active = ($month_number==='09' && $month_year==='2017') ? 'active': '';
echo '<div class="item '.$active.'">';
```

Comment: Use above code it helps you to resolve your issue... @Balloon Fight